# Кроссбраузерное тестирование сайтов

Tags: html, html5, тестирование, кроссбраузерность

Какие **бесплатные** инструменты вы используете для тестирования *кроссбраузерности* сайтов? В сети много платных онлайн инструментов, есть бесплатные, которые генерируют скриншоты, но это долго и не даёт желаемого результата.

На ПК всех браузеров не установить.

Интересуют основные: Chrome, Firefox и Safari, Opera и всеми любимый Internet Explorer.

Comment: "*Chrome, Firefox и Safari, Opera, Internet Explorer*" почему же не установить?

Comment: @Pink Tux, можно установить, а как насчёт версий? И Safari на Win вроде с 12 года не обновляется.

Comment: @Pink Tux, да и ПК элементарно может не у всех тянет кучу запущенных браузеров. Проще иметь одну программу или сайт, где это можно сделать. От сюда и вопрос.

Comment: Если под Windows, то у FF, Chrome и оперы есть портабельные версии (см. portableapps.com), их сколько угодно поставить можно. IE - пары версий мало? Одну реальную, вторую в виртуалке. Вот сафари - да, непонятно... А зачем запускать сразу все одновременно? Да и не поверю я, что у разработчика/дизайнера рабочая машина настолько дохлая.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://browsershots.org/  - бесплатный и удобный.
Кстати, можете предоставить свои ресурсы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ну нажал проверить, и нифига не происходит)))

Comment: может у вас NOscript стоит? отключите для этого сайта))))))))

Comment: нет, там написано - очередь, 15 минут, мда уж тестирование))

Comment: @Jean-Claude, как видите, других бесплатных вариантов вообще нет. Да и платные мне не очень понравились, я попробовал тестовые версии.

Comment: Я многое могу понять)... но если у кого-то   не хватает ума прочитать на eng, зарегистрируйся - и получи не 50, а 150 браузеров - это к  ... И еще - этот сервис помогает накрутить от 10 до 120 посетителей) читайте man

Answer (score 0):

1. [browserstack](https://www.browserstack.com)
2. [crossbrowsertesting](https://crossbrowsertesting.com/)
3. [browseemall](http://www.browseemall.com/)

Все платное.